# Not Equal "<>" not working

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to build a simple query in Access 2010.

```
SELECT tblData.URSampleID, tblData.DateInfoReqSent
FROM tblData
INNER JOIN tblLinkData ON tblData.URSampleID = tblLinkData.URSampleID
WHERE (((tblData.DateInfoReqSent)<>[tblLinkData].[DateInfoReqSent]));
```

This does not return any values. It should return three rows of data in my dummy db.

However;

```
SELECT tblData.URSampleID, tblData.DateInfoReqSent
FROM tblData
INNER JOIN tblLinkData ON tblData.URSampleID = tblLinkData.URSampleID
WHERE (((tblData.DateInfoReqSent)=[tblLinkData].[DateInfoReqSent]));
```

DOES work and returns the correct data.

`[DateInfoReqSent]` is a date field in both tables.

I tried using `NOT` as in:

```
SELECT tblData.URSampleID, tblData.DateInfoReqSent
FROM tblData
INNER JOIN tblLinkData ON tblData.URSampleID = tblLinkData.URSampleID
WHERE (NOT((tblData.DateInfoReqSent)=[tblLinkData].[DateInfoReqSent]));
```

But that gives the same result as `<>` above.

What is wrong with my syntax? Thanks in advance.

Additional Info as requested.

tblLinkData

```
URSampleID  DateInfoReqSent
15001003    7/31/2014
15004027    7/31/2014
15000265    7/31/2014
15001794    7/31/2014
15002246    8/4/2014
15004088    8/4/2014
15006457    8/4/2014
15000524    8/4/2014
```

tblData

```
URSampleID  DateInfoReqSent
15001003    
15004027    
15000265    
15001794    7/31/2014
15002246    8/4/2014
15004088    8/4/2014
15006457    8/4/2014
15000524    8/4/2014
```

After testing the answers below, here is what I came up with:

```
SELECT tblData.URSampleID, tblData.DateInfoReqSent
FROM tblData INNER JOIN tblLinkData ON tblData.URSampleID = tblLinkData.URSampleID
WHERE (nz(tblData.DateInfoReqSent,'') <> nz([tblLinkData].[DateInfoReqSent],''));
```

and/or

```
SELECT tblData.URSampleID, tblData.DateInfoReqSent
FROM tblData INNER JOIN tblLinkData ON tblData.URSampleID = tblLinkData.URSampleID
WHERE (((tblData.DateInfoReqSent)<>tblLinkData.DateInfoReqSent)) Or
(((tblData.DateInfoReqSent) Is Null) And ((tblLinkData.DateInfoReqSent) Is Not Null)) Or
(((tblData.DateInfoReqSent) Is Not Null) And ((tblLinkData.DateInfoReqSent) Is Null));
```

Both of which work.

Thanks for the help. I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Please post a small sample of rows from each table so we can understand what the data looks like and how the joining relationship affects your `WHERE` condition.

Comment: If you remove the where clause and look at the results, are the three rows you currently expect in the results?

Comment: My question is, is there a matching row in both tables on the URSampleID that are not showing up like you expect?

Comment: To answer your questions.

1. Added data. See original question.

2. Yes, the rows show when there are no criteria. All eight rows of data are returned.

3. In the "<>" query NO results are returned. NONE.
If I use "=" as a different query the correct five rows of results are returned.

Comment: I can't fully test in Access 2010, but trying the same setup (based on your data) in sql server 2008, the data seems to have worked.  Are you sure the example you gave matches the setup you actually have?  Look at the attached SQL Fiddle.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c643/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `where` clause:

```
WHERE tblData.DateInfoReqSent <> [tblLinkData].[DateInfoReqSent]
```

is not necessarily what you are doing what you expect.  If both columns have values, then only rows with non-matching values go through.  However, rows where one or both of the values are `NULL` will also fail the comparison.  `NULL`s result in failed comparisons (except for `is null`), even for `<>`.

You can use `NZ()` to fill in a value:

```
WHERE NZ(tblData.DateInfoReqSent, '') <> NZ([tblLinkData].[DateInfoReqSent], '')
```

Or explicitly include the logic:

```
WHERE tblData.DateInfoReqSent <> [tblLinkData].[DateInfoReqSent] or
      tblData.DateInfoReqSent is null and [tblLinkData].[DateInfoReqSent] is not null or
      tblData.DateInfoReqSent is not null [tblLinkData].[DateInfoReqSent] is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, after I added a comment on your post, I wonder if you have a null versus a '' issue in your db.

Using your main query in your post, I ran it against this setup in SQL Fiddle (inserting '' for the dates that didn't post in tblData) here:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c643/1

The 3 days returned.   However, when I inserted nulls into the mix instead of the '', I got none back.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/325ab/1

You need to either trap for nulls when querying your database, or make sure empty ticks are put into your database.  The simplest way would be to change your WHERE clause as such (you don't need all those extra parentheses):

```
 WHERE isnull(tblData.DateInfoReqSent, '')<> isnull([tblLinkData].[DateInfoReqSent],'');
```

**Disclaimer:**  I'm only able to confirm this through SQL Server 2008; I presume Access setup wouldn't be too much different in this case.

Comment: Yes, I was about to respond that where you show ' ' in your fiddle I have nulls. Still "null"<>"actual date" so I don't understand why <> doesn't work.
But, I guess I'll have to add a "OR(IsNull())".

Comment: I just updated my code, based on sql server 2008.   you could simply make the change to your where clause.

Comment: I can't fully answer why nulls do this when it comes to datetime values, but I can only say is that they work differently than empty values. I've grown to simply checking if null, throw an empty value or a '01/01/1900' value, depending on circumstances.

Comment: It doesn't look like Access 2010 supports using IsNull this way. In Access its just a Boolean test and just returns True or False. But, if I wrapped it in a IIF test it might work.

Comment: Sounds like Gordon's post is your answer then.    :)